# Why does Instagram image source have a Facebook favicon?

Tags: facebook, instagram

Stumbled across this. Does anyone know why Instagram uses the Facebook favicon?
I know Facebook owns Instagram.

[image: Zucks Insta Image]

Comment: Because they used the wrong favicon.ico? Because they re-purposed a server and didn't replace the favicon.ico? Because it's actually on a Facebook server and the domain points to it? Honestly, does it matter?

Comment: @AlE. No it doesn't matter. The question was out of curiosity.